# Time Limit Exceeded for CodeChef Easy problem - STRQ (Chef and Strings)

Tags: java, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I was working through a codechef easy problem [here](http://www.codechef.com/problems/STRQ).

I've got to a solution, but it only passes the Subtask #1. For the other two subtasks, it shows TLE (Time Limit Exceeded - which is 1 second).

```
package com.codechef.solutions;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ChefAndStrings {

  private static final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  private static StringTokenizer tokenizer;

  private static String specialString = "";
  private static int numberOfQueries = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintStream out = System.out;
    try {
      specialString = br.readLine();
      numberOfQueries = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

      for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQueries; i++) {
        String nextQuery = nextQuery();
        out.println(getGoodStringCounts(nextQuery));
      }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      out.println("Exception occurred while reading input");
    }
  }

  private static String nextQuery() throws IOException {
    return br.readLine();
  }

  private static int getGoodStringCounts(String query) {
    tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(query, " ");
    char startLetter = tokenizer.nextToken().charAt(0);
    char endLetter = tokenizer.nextToken().charAt(0);
    int startIndex = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()) - 1;
    int endIndex = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()) - 1;

    int[] startLetterIndices = allIndicesGreaterThanMin(startLetter, startIndex);
    int[] endLetterIndices = allIndicesLessThanMax(endLetter, endIndex);

    int total = 0;
    int beginEndIndexFrom = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < startLetterIndices.length; i++) {
      int index = startLetterIndices[i];
      for (int j = beginEndIndexFrom; j < endLetterIndices.length; j++) {
        if (endLetterIndices[j] > index) {
          beginEndIndexFrom = j;
          total += (endLetterIndices.length - beginEndIndexFrom);
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    return total;
  }

  private static int[] allIndicesGreaterThanMin(char letter, int startIndex) {
    int[] indices = new int[specialString.length() / 2];
    int currentIndex = 0;
    int index = specialString.indexOf(letter, startIndex);
    while (index != -1) {
      indices[currentIndex++] = index;
      startIndex = index + 1;
      index = specialString.indexOf(letter, startIndex);
    }
    int[] result = new int[currentIndex];
    System.arraycopy(indices, 0, result, 0, result.length);
    return result;
  }

  private static int[] allIndicesLessThanMax(char letter, int endIndex) {
    int[] indices = new int[specialString.length() / 2];
    int currentIndex = 0;
    int index = specialString.indexOf(letter);
    while (index != -1 && index <= endIndex) {
      indices[currentIndex++] = index;
      index = specialString.indexOf(letter, index + 1);
    }
    int[] result = new int[currentIndex];
    System.arraycopy(indices, 0, result, 0, result.length);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Initially I used `List<Integer>` to store the indices, but then moved to `int[]`, after I got the error first time. Still it isn't accepting. Can you see some possible optimization there?

Comment: You need to use a more efficient algorithm. What you have now is `O(q * n)` or even `O(q * n * n)` time in the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient algorithm that requires `O(n)` time for initialization and `O(1)` time per query.

1. Let's fix a pair (start letter, end letter)(there are only 12 such combinations). 
   Now we can precompute the following value: `count(len)` - the number of strings that start with the start letter, end with the end letter and are located inside the prefix of length `len`. Here is a pseudo that does it:

   ```
   for start_letter <- letters:
       for end_letter <- letters:
           if start_letter != end_letter:
               start_letter_count = 0
               strings_count = 0
               for i <- 0 ... s.lenght() - 1:
                   if s[i] == start_letter:
                       start_letters_count++
                   else if s[i] == end_letter:
                       strings_count += start_letters_count
                   count(i, start_letter, end_letter) = strings_count
   ```
2. The answer to a `(left, right, start_letter, end_letter)` is
   `count(right, start_letter, end_letter) - count(left - 1, start_letter, end_letter) - count_letter(left, right, end_letter) * count_letter(0, left - 1, start_letter)`, where `count_letter(left, right, c)` is the number of occurrences of a char `c` between `left` and `right` inclusively(it can be done in `O(1)` time with `O(n)` preprocessing using prefix sums).  Why does this formula work?
   We can take all string that end before `right`. Now we need to subtract the number of strings that end before `left`. We also should subtract the number of such strings that start before `left` but end between `left` and `right`.

The time complexity is `O(n + q)` because we traverse the given string once for each pair of start and end letters, and then we use one formula that is computed in `O(1)` to answer each query.

Comment: Looks promising. Will try your solution later on.